# How to apply multiple filters to a dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame that looks like

```
+-------+-------+
| Code1 | Code2 |
+-------+-------+
| A     |     1 |
| B     |     1 |
| A     |     2 |
| B     |     2 |
| C     |     2 |
| D     |     2 |
| D     |     3 |
| F     |     3 |
| G     |     3 |
+-------+-------+
```

I then want to apply a unique set of filters like so:

- Scenario 1 -> filter on Code1 IN (A,B)
- Scenario 2 -> filter on Code1 IN (A,D) and Code2 IN (2,3)
- Scenario 3 -> filter on Code2 = 2

The result of applying the filter should be a data frame that looks like:

```
+-------+-------+----------+
| Code1 | Code2 | Scenario |
+-------+-------+----------+
| A     |     1 |        1 |
| B     |     1 |        1 |
| A     |     2 |        1 |
| B     |     2 |        1 |
| A     |     2 |        2 |
| D     |     2 |        2 |
| D     |     3 |        2 |
| A     |     2 |        3 |
| B     |     2 |        3 |
| C     |     2 |        3 |
| D     |     2 |        3 |
+-------+-------+----------+
```

**QUESTION**: What is the most efficient way to do this with spark via python?

I am new to spark, so I am really asking from a conceptual level and don't need an explicit solution. I am aiming to achieve as much parallelism as possible in the operation. My real-life example involves using an initial data frame with 38 columns that is on the order of 100MB to a couple GB as a csv file and I typically have at most 100-150 scenarios.

The original design of the solution was to process each scenario filter sequentially and union the resulting filtered data frames together, but I feel like that negates the whole point of using spark.

***EDIT***: Does it though? For each scenario, I would filter and then union, which are both transformations (lazy eval). Would the eventual execution plan be smart enough to automatically parallelize the multiple unique filters?

Isn't there a way we can apply the filters in parallel, e.g., apply scenario filter 1 at the same time as applying filters 2 and 3? Would we have to "blow up" the initial dataframe N times, where N = # of scenario filters, append a Scenario # column to the new data frame, and apply one big filter that looks something like:

```
WHERE (Scenario = 1 AND Code1 IN (A,B)) OR
      (Scenario = 2 AND Code1 IN (A,D) AND Code2 IN (2,3)) OR
      (Scenario = 3 AND Code2 = 2)
```

And if that does end up being the most efficient way, isn't it also dependent on how much memory the "blown up" data frame takes? If the "blown up" data frame takes up more memory than what my cluster has, am I going to have to process only as many scenarios as can fit in memory?

Answer (score 0):

you can apply all filters at once:

```
  data.withColumn("scenario",
    when('code1.isin("A", "B"), 1).otherwise(
      when('code1.isin("A", "D") && 'code2.isin("2","3"), 2).otherwise(
        when('code2==="2",3)
      )
    )
  ).show()
```

but you have one more problem, for example values (A,2) could be in all of your scenarios 1,2,3. In this case you could try smth like that:

```
  data.withColumn("s1", when('code1.isin("A", "B"), 1).otherwise(0))
    .withColumn("s2",when('code1.isin("A", "D") && 'code2.isin("2","3"), 1).otherwise(0))
    .withColumn("s3",when('code2==="2",1).otherwise(0))
    .show()
```

output:

```
+-----+-----+---+---+---+
|code1|code2| s1| s2| s3|
+-----+-----+---+---+---+
|    A|    1|  1|  0|  0|
|    B|    1|  1|  0|  0|
|    A|    2|  1|  1|  1|
|    B|    2|  1|  0|  1|
|    A|    2|  1|  1|  1|
|    D|    2|  0|  1|  1|
|    D|    3|  0|  1|  0|
|    A|    2|  1|  1|  1|
|    B|    2|  1|  0|  1|
|    C|    2|  0|  0|  1|
|    D|    2|  0|  1|  1|
+-----+-----+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks @AndrzejS. Your latter solution seems like something that could work. However, in order to get to the desired output stated in the question, I would have to take the [code1,code2,s1,s2,s3,...] data frame and collapse it to [code1,code2,scenario]. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that, keeping in mind the desire for parallelism? I'm looking into this now, but figure you might already know the answer :X

Answer (score 0):

In the EDIT to my question, I questioned whether the lazy evaluation is the key to the problem. After doing some research in the Spark UI, I have concluded that even though my original solution *looks like* it is applying transformations (filter then union) sequentially for each scenario, it is actually applying all the transformations simultaneously, once an action (e.g., dataframe.count()) is called. The [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk6p6.png) represents the Event Timeline from the transformation phase of the dataframe.count() job.

The job includes 96 scenarios each with a unique filter on the original data frame. You can see that my local machine is running 8 tasks simultaneously, where each task represents a filter from one of the scenarios.

In conclusion, Spark takes care of optimizing the filters to run in parallel, once an action has been called on the resulting dataframe.